# In Lay man's terms what's the difference between a LossFunction and an OptimizationAlgorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I get the part that training a network is all about finding the right *weights* with ***Optimization Algorithms*** deciding how *weights* are *updated* until the *one* needed to get the right prediction is come about.

So the million dollar **que$tion$** to the main one are:

**(1.)** If *`optimization algorithms`* updates the *weights* what do *`loss functions`* do to the *weights* of the network?

**(2.)** Are *`loss functions`* only specific to the output layer of a neural network? (most examples I see with the *`deeplearning4j`* framework implement it at the output layer).

> > **P.S:** *I really want to understand the basic difference between this two in the simplest way possible. I am not looking for anything complex or with some mathematical explosions.*

Answer (score 3):

The `optimization algorithm` tries to find the `minimum` of the `loss function`. At which points the `weights` are ideal.

Comment: does this mean optimization algorithms use loss functions to update weights?